# Qlik Set Analysis and aggregating across date ranges

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I am trying to use Qlik set analysis and range sum to compute the total number of records that were active at a some point in the month

For example, if these are the records:

```
id  state   created_date    modified_date
1   expired 01/12/2014  10/12/2014
2   expired 01/12/2014  10/03/2015
3   active  01/12/2014  01/12/2014
4   expired 10/01/2015  12/01/2015
5   expired 10/01/2015  11/03/2015
6   active  10/02/2015  10/02/2015
7   expired 10/03/2015  11/03/2015
```

The expected o/p is

```
Dec-14  3
Jan-15  4
Feb-15  4
Mar-15  5
```

E.g: For Jan-2015 the result should be 4 - 
  1 active record from Dec 2014 + 2 created in Jan + 1 from Dec which actually expired in March 2015

modified_date is updated when a record is expired

So I tried this:

```
rangesum(above(Count({$<[state] = {'active'} >} id), 0,12))
+ Count({1<[state] ={'expired'}, modified_date.Calendar.Month ={">=$(created_date.Calendar.Month)"}>} id)
```

the second count statement is wrong. How can I aggregate the records which are currently not active but were active at some point during the month.Is it possible to achieve this without using a Master calendar ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to this would be to amend your data model to include an active date like below.

```
ActiveMonthsRaw:
Load ID
    ,date(monthstart(created_date),''MMM-YY) as ActiveMonthFormat
resident SourceTable
where state ='active';

ActiveMonthsRaw:
Load ID
    ,date(monthstart(modified_date),''MMM-YY) as ActiveMonthFormat
resident SourceTable
where state ='expired';

ActiveMonths:
Load distinct ID
    ,ActiveMonthFormat as ActiveMonth;

drop table ActiveMonthsRaw;
```

It would then be a case of doing a distinct count of ID by the Active Month. No Set analysis in sight!